# How to avoid C# assembly dependency propagation?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, dependency-management

I have created a C# solution (lets call it "ServiceProviderLib"), consisting of several class libraries with solution internal assembly references/dependencies. The solution has just one class library, which exposes a public interface intended to be used as api by some other applications.

A(public) ---depends-on---> B ---depends-on---> C.

Now I am developing an application (lets call it "ServiceUserApp") which should dynamically link to the api of the "ServiceProviderLib".

App ---depends-on---> A.

To resolve the dependency to the "ServiceProviderLib" I am using a handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve.

I would have expected that I have to resolve just the dependency to A. As the ServiceProviderLib should resolve its internals dependencies for it self.

But for the App I have to resolve all dependencies to A + B + C individually.

Is there a way to avoid this?

---

Some information about the background of the question:
I know that there are many pros and cons for using static/dynmaic linking/resolving libraries.

To be more precise, about what I mean by static/dynamic:

static:
In the App I would reference library A and would let the visual studio property "Local Copy" at the default value "true". This would lead to a copy of the dll in the build directory. In this case there is no need for manual dll resolving.

dynamic:
In the App I would reference library A and would set the visual studio property "Local Copy" explicitely to the value "false". In this case the dll will not be copied to the build directory ... and has to be resolved at runtime.

I used both variants for quite a long time and made the experience that dynamic linking lead to less problems in my special environment. Therefore I decided to stick to dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If by "dynamically link" you mean that you are loading assemblies at runtime via reflection, then you don't automatically get the same automatic dependency loading as a compile-time reference would give you. (There is no such thing as dynamic/static linking in CLR.)

If you are using compile time references, then your code is touching at least one type from each assembly and will need a direct reference to the defining assembly to resolve them properly. If you remove the references to B and C and compile you will see exactly which B/C types you are referencing, and where.

Comment: Hi Artfunkel, thank you for your respose. I updated my description to give some extra information. Maybe that is helpful for better understanding of my problem.